# Bootstrap 5 Off-Canvas left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I got the code below from the official bootstrap 5 [demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/offcanvas-navbar/) and for the life of me, can't figure how to move the off-canvas menu from Left-to-Right. The documentation code to place the `offcanvas-start` and the demo code are completely different.

**JSFiddle DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/fn0vypzt/**

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .offcanvas-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #343a40;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .offcanvas-collapse.open {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

JS:

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  document.querySelector('#navbarSideCollapse').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
  })
})()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking to have the menu slide in from the left instead of from the right, changing `.offcanvas-collapse` from `left: 100%` to `right: 100%` and `.offcanvas-collapse.open` from `transform: translateX(-100%);` to 100% (no minus) should do what you need.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict'

    document.querySelector('#navbarSideCollapse').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
    })
})()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    @media (max-width: 991.98px) {
        .offcanvas-collapse {
            position: fixed;
            top: 56px;
            /* Height of navbar */
            bottom: 0;
            right: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 1rem;
            padding-left: 1rem;
            overflow-y: auto;
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #343a40;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .offcanvas-collapse.open {
            visibility: visible;
            transform: translateX(100%);
        }
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow! So simple. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**.offcanvas-start** places offcanvas on the left of the viewport.
Use this class on the **offcanvas** **div** below **toggler button**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasTop" aria-controls="offcanvasTop">Toggle top offcanvas</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-top" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasTop" aria-labelledby="offcanvasTopLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 id="offcanvasTopLabel">Offcanvas top</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ++++ The mention of `.offcanvas-start` in the Bootstrap docs is a bit hidden and you won't find it (like me) in the Navbar section. It is available in the Offcanvas component doc page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/offcanvas/#placement

Answer (score 1):

Set class, `offcavas-end` to `offcanvas-start`.

```html
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
```